# Is there some generic data structure to compare lists of objects and find most equal among them?

Tags: python, data-structures

I will use Python to show a code (because this solution for Python written code) but this question is language independent.

Let's say I have 2 lists of objects. I can't use object ids as primary keys for those objects.

An object can look like(real objects much more complicated and have nested structures):

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, prop1, prop2, prop3):
        self.prop1 = prop1
        self.prop2 = prop2
        self.prop3 = prop3
```

Lists look like:

```
list1 = [A(1, 2, 3), A(4, 5, 6), A(7, 8, 9)]
list2 = [A(1, 10, 11), A(4, 5, 6), A(1, 4, 9), A(10, 11, 12)]
```

While comparing objects I use the number of equal properties as a score.

For example:

```
A(1, 2, 3) == A(1, 10, 11) gives 1, because only 1 == 1
A(4, 5, 6) == A(4, 5, 6) gives 3, because 4 == 4, 5 == 5, 6 == 6
A(7, 8, 9) == A(10, 11, 12) gives 0, because there are no equal items
```

After comparison of all objects form `list1` with every object from `list2`, I get something I call similarity matrix which will look like this:

```
[
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 3, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
]
```

After that I take max element from list, which is `3`, delete row and column to which this number belongs (row=1, column=1), delete by position those object from `list1`, `list2` and repeat until there are no items in similarity matrix which are greater than threshold(zero in current example).

Similarity matrix after a first step:

```
[
    [1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
]
```

Lists after a first step:

```
list1 = [A(1, 2, 3), A(7, 8, 9)]
list2 = [A(1, 10, 11), A(1, 4, 9), A(10, 11, 12)]
```

By those actions, I will get most equal objects by popping them by position from lists and everything left in lists I mark as not equal.

I want to know if I reinventing a wheel and there is some data structure which can help with this? Do you see any visible improvements which can speed up current solution?

Comment: Could you somehow use the `obj.__dict__` attribute. Maybe there is a standard `dict` similarity library?

Comment: @JamesSchinner Actually those objects use slots but it's not a problem to convert it to dict. Thaks for idea, will try to find dict similarity info.

Comment: Just to clarify. Are you comparing same numbers on same positions or is it A(1,2,3) ~ A(5,1,7) = 1? Taking '~' is similarity relation.

Comment: @ikac I would say same properties `(obj1.prop1 == obj2.prop1)`

Comment: @Georgy Is there a way to move it to another hub?

Comment: @ViacheslavKondratiuk Only moderators can do that. I will flag the question for their attention. If they agree on that, they will move it.

Comment: @Georgy when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways that I can think of right now are:

- using dictionaries and sets, or
- objects with `sim_level` method.

## Dictionaries and Sets

```
list1 = [
    {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3},
    {'x': 7, 'y': 8, 'z': 9}
]

list2 = [
    {'x': 1, 'y': 10, 'z': 11},
    {'x': 1, 'y': 4, 'z': 9},
    {'x': 10, 'y': 11, 'z': 12},
]

def sim_level(a, b):
    # this creates set of pairs e.g. ('prop1', 2)
    sa = set(a.items())  
    sb = set(b.items())

    # here you intersect them and count number of intersecting elements
    return len(sa.intersection(sb))
```

Then its all about iterating through a product of those lists and counting weight and then removing objects from both lists that have biggest similarity level.

## Objects

This would include having object similar to what you already use, but have additional method `sim_level` that is going to compare to another instance of same class.

```
class A():

    def __init__(self, prop1, prop2, prop3):
        self.prop1 = prop1
        self.prop2 = prop2
        self.prop3 = prop3

    def sim_level(self, other):
        s = 0
        if self.prop1 == other.prop1: s += 1
        if self.prop2 == other.prop2: s += 1
        if self.prop3 == other.prop3: s += 1
        return s
```

Then you continue as if you would with dictionaries suggestion.